# How to cancel an async WebApi action after timeout?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, async-await, asp.net-4.5

Using ASP.Net WebAPI, I have a controller with an asynchronous action similar to the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> DoSomething(string foo)
{
  var result = await MyAsynchronousTask(foo);
  return result;
}
```

What this controller does is unimportant.  Whats important is that it is awaiting an asynchronous task using the new .net 4.5 async/await support.

**Question:** How do I tell it to time out after a specified duration?  I don't necessarily want to cancel the task, I just want to prevent the caller from hanging on forever.  (Although, I would be interested in seeing it both ways.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made a version in LINQPad with the 'C# Program' selection - it compiles and runs with output of 2 lines, showing both the time-out and success cases:

> Timeout of 00:00:05 expired
>
> Successfully got result of foo

Here's the snippet:

```
void Main()
{
    CallGetStringWithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Wait();
    CallGetStringWithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)).Wait();
}

public async Task CallGetStringWithTimeout(TimeSpan callTimeout, TimeSpan callAddedDelay)
{
    var myTask = GetStringAsync(callAddedDelay);
    await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(callTimeout), myTask);
    if (myTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Successfully got result of {0}", await myTask);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Timeout of {0} expired", callTimeout);
    }
}

public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(TimeSpan addedDelay)
{
    await Task.Delay(addedDelay);
    return "foo";
}
```

However, the 'normal' way is using [CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) and specifying your timeout as [the ctor param](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139229.aspx).  If you already have a CancellationTokenSource, you can call [the CancelAfter method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter.aspx) on it, which will schedule the cancellation for the specified timeout.

Comment: This doesn't work because I have a Task<string> and Task.Delay is just a Task.  I need to wrap it somehow I think.  Ideas?

Comment: I think I got it.  Task.Delay(timeout).ContinueWith<string>(x=> null) seems to work.  Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Not sure why you would need to wrap it - Task.WhenAny will take it fine, just treating it as a non-generic Task.  If the status shows it ran fine, then you could either access the Result property, or await it, or whatever (you're in a conditional that it has completed, so no worry about blocking)

Comment: I'll flesh it out to a more complete example, hopefully that'll help. :)

Comment: Try it.  Without the .ContinueWith<string>(x=>null) it will not compile.  Type mismatch between the nongeneric Task and the generic Task<T>.

Comment: @Matt - the new code I put compiles and runs fine - am I misunderstanding something?