# WebAPI Timeout Using Built in pipeline

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

So I would first like to preempt some of the duplicate question flags given questions like the following.  In fact one of these guys got hit with some of that overzealousness:
[How to cancel an async WebApi action after timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047176/how-to-cancel-an-async-webapi-action-after-timeout)
[web api apicontroller timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717795/web-api-apicontroller-timeout)

I am looking for ANY way to enforce a timeout, either globally or at the controller level.  Note that this works differently between WebAPI and MVC4.  Specifically for controllers returning a Task, but as far as I can tell non-task returning controllers for the WebAPI do not have this capability either.  What is interesting is that that first linked question implements a home-grown manual timeout which while clever, that doesn't seem like something that should be handled at that level. I have confirmed that the following response on codeplex is not correct:
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/245

I just want a confirmation one way or the other that Microsoft has thus far neglected to provide a way to timeout WebAPI requests.